# Javascript rebuild a JSON array in another structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array result from an API get in this form:

```
var data = {
"metadata": [{
    "colIndex": 0,
    "colType": "String",
    "colName": "Territory"
}, {
    "colIndex": 1,
    "colType": "String",
    "colName": "Region"
}, {
    "colIndex": 2,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "Market"
}, {
    "colIndex": 3,
    "colType": "Numeric",
    "colName": "Sales"
}],
"resultset": [
    ["Europe",    'France',     null,         100],        
    ["Europe",    'Germany',   150,       500],
    ["Europe",    'Austria',   250,       200],
    ["Europe",    'Poland',   220,      100],        
    ["Europe",    'Italy',      120,       200],
    ["Europe",    'Bulgaria',      40,      500],
    ["Europe",    'Romania',      450,      400]
]};
```

I want to transform this dataset in another structure:

```
var data = [{
"country": [
    ['France', null],
    ['Germany', 150],
    ['Austria', 250],
    ['Poland', 220],
    ['Italy', 120],
    ['Bulgaria', 40],
    [Romania', 450]
],
"name": "Market" // this is metadata.colName
},{
"country": [
    ['France', 100],
    ['Germany', 500],
    ['Austria', 200],
    ['Poland', 100],
    ['Italy', 200],
    ['Bulgaria', 500],
    [Romania', 400]
],
"name": "Sales" // this is metadata.colName
}]
```

I tried using some loop variation, but i gave up. Here is my last [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxg1974/Cmbhx/).

Thank you all for hints or answers.

Comment: Do you need to extract collumn names from json data?

Comment: yes. var data is the result of an ajax.

Comment: I mean "Market" and "Sales" are extracted from ajax result data or they are static?

Comment: "Market" and "Sales" are extracted from ajax result, see metadata colName index 2 and 3. Aren't static. Represent numerical columns in resultset. Ex: ["Europe",    'France',     null,         100] from resultset have in metadata (in order) "colName": "Territory","colName": "Region",**"colName": "Market","colName": "Sales"**

Comment: And still I don't get by what rules you combine new data: how you get which collumns to extract (why you skip Territory and why each time you use Region). Detailed formula for new data generation would be great and easier to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use embedded [`.map()` iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate the outer `Array` from `metadata`, starting at the 3rd element, with each `name` and `country` from `resultset` within that:

```
var countryIndex = 1;
var startingIndex = 2;

// for each desired metadata, generate an object with name and
// a country collection of the respective resultset data
data = data.metadata.slice(startingIndex).map(function (meta) {
    return {
        country: data.resultset.map(function (result) {
            return [
                result[countryIndex],
                result[meta.colIndex]
            ];
        }),
        name: meta.colName
    };
});

console.log(data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n943m/

You can also create empty `country` `Array`s first and use the iterator variables to find the `country` to [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to:

```
var revised = [];
var countryIndex = 1;
var startingIndex = 2;

var dr = data.resultset;
var dm = data.metadata;

// initialize the name and country objects with an empty Array to fill
for (var j = startingIndex; j < dm.length; j++) {
    revised.push({
        country: [],
        name: dm[j].colName
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < dr.length; i++) {
    // repeat the same loop used to initialize
    for (var j = startingIndex; j < dm.length; j++) {
        // subtract to start back at `0` for `revised`
        revised[j - startingIndex].country.push([
            dr[i][countryIndex],
            dr[i][ dm[j].colIndex ]
        ]);
    }
}

console.log(revised);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krDXV/

Either should allow the collection to adjust to the number of columns included in `metadata` and `resultset`.

Comment: Thank you, the first example is exactly what i want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your initial ajax data there are at least 2 ways:

1. Convert each resultset row to element with named properties and then convert to what you need.
2. Get collumn indexes of required collumns for extracting data from resultset and make new objects from these values.

Here is working example of second way:

```
var data = {
    "metadata": [{
        "colIndex": 0,
            "colType": "String",
            "colName": "Territory"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 1,
            "colType": "String",
            "colName": "Region"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 2,
            "colType": "Numeric",
            "colName": "Market"
    }, {
        "colIndex": 3,
            "colType": "Numeric",
            "colName": "Sales"
    }],
        "resultset": [
        ["Europe", 'France', null, 100],
        ["Europe", 'Germany', 150, 500],
        ["Europe", 'Austria', 250, 200],
        ["Europe", 'Poland', 220, 100],
        ["Europe", 'Italy', 120, 200],
        ["Europe", 'Bulgaria', 40, 500],
        ["Europe", 'Romania', 450, 400]
    ]
};


var rv = []; //Converted AJAX data.
var m_markets = [];
var m_sales = [];

var ind_region = 1;
var ind_market = 2; //Get index of "Market" collumn
var ind_sales = 3; //Get index of "Sales" collumn

if (Array.isArray(data.resultset)){
    data.resultset.forEach(function(e,i){
        m_markets.push([e[ind_region], e[ind_market]]);
        m_sales.push([e[ind_region], e[ind_sales]]);
    });
}

rv.push({
    country: m_markets,
    name: "Market"
});
rv.push({
    country: m_sales,
    name: "Sales"
});

console.log('Converted JSON: ', rv); // Look at console.
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cmbhx/1/

Comment: your example is good and result is what i want, but numerical columns are dynamic. You create arrays m_markets and  m_sales static, bat i have 20 numerical columns. Ex:["Europe", 'Germany', 150, 500, 250, 420] in resultset and in metadata  "colName": "Territory","colName": "Region","colName": "Market","colName": "Sales",**"colName":"SalesInSide","colName":"SalesOutSide"**

Comment: now you have ways how to make it with static data, now make it work with dynamic data. I will be able to help you only after 10 hours. (I need to sleep).